# AWS Ec2 "Connection refused"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I used to be able to connect to my ec2 instance but suddenly I am no longer able to and I do not know why.  My security group is the same, allowing ssh from anywhere.  I have some information below regarding the errors that I am getting.  Please can someone advise?

From FileZilla I am getting:

```
 Error:         ssh_init: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
 Error:         Could not connect to server
```

From the terminal I am just getting:

```
ssh: connect to host ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: If you were using `-i filename` for an 'identity' file (which is really a key file) and remove the `-i` but keep `filename` that makes the command totally wrong and broken. If you want to use an identity file AND get more detailed info, use BOTH options like `ssh -vv -i filename`. But the details shown by `ssh -v` or `-vv` are about the SSH protocol; connection refused means the SSH protocol didn't even start and `ssh` won't have any useful details to show.

Comment: @dave I have updated the question.  Any suggestions on what I can do to reoclve the issue?

Comment: @jamesMcKey Could you please check if you can telnet to the IP and CPU utilization of the instance from the AWS Console?

Comment: Did you restart the instance recently? Do you have EIP assigned?

Comment: Tried ssh-ing using the IP address? I noticed you're using the public DNS name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have the same issue i did the following troubleshooting steps and it still gives the same

> ssh: connect to host [my public DNS] port 22: Connection refused

1. i checked the key ".pem" file and its correct on the right directory
2. no code edits as it used to work fine last night and suddenly this error appeared
3. i went to the AWS console, selected the instance , and clicked on connect and copied the SSH command to make sure that no typos , and the command is correct
4. i tried with -v , still same issue.
5. tried to reboot the instance , no progress
6. stop then start the instance , no progress
7. tried to detach the volum and re attach the volum back , no progress
8. i changed the instance type from t2.micro to t2.small , no progress
9. checked the security group , port 22 is assigned to all IPs and no problem with the security group at all as it used to work fine
10. tried from different computers from different networks, same issue
11. created new instance , i can access the new one but cant ssh to the old one still

my best guess is that the ssh daemon is not enabled  but how to access it if i cant ssh to the instance

Comment: Did you ever figure out if your ssh daemon wasn't running, and the reason why? I'm having the same problem, and I mounted the volume of the broken instance onto another instance and checked my /etc/ssh/sshd_config, and it looks fine. Not sure what else to check.